# check null value in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have 2 columns in gridview I want to check if the column is null then the column will hidden .. I used many ways but I can't get the right result

here is my code

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text == "")
    {
        e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I'm tried also to check equal null word but the same problem The columns not hidden

Comment: The documentation for DataGridViewCell says that Visible is "get" only, not settable and that it tells you if it resides in a column that is visible. So, I wouldn't expect this to compile. Anyway, if  you want to make a column visible or not, do it to a column, not a cell.

Comment: You have to set the visibility outside the RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  string val = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[0]);  //check first cell value
  if(string.IsNullorEmpty(val) )             
  {
     gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;     //Hides First Column
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not work , still the columns is appear

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value))
{
    GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: the ( Value ) word has the red line bellow !?

Comment: check GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8]

Comment: BTW, do you want to hide that column for some rows only or hide the entire column from the grid?

Comment: I want to hide the entire column

Answer (score 0):

Try change in your query for example:

```
select id,name,ISNULL(rate,0) from example
else  use IsNull(rate,'')
```

you have to change like this and put query in your `Bind()` function

Comment: defaultly it takes 0 then you can check your conditions then it came.. Im not sure but try this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure can try this way :

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             // This line will get the reference to the underlying row
             DataRowView _row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
             if (_row = null)
             {
               GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
}
```